# character convertion with CSV file

Tags: php, csv, character

I have faced a problem whenever exporting a CSV file with PHP. I have a MYSQL query like

```
SELECT `interest_id`,`interest_name`,`interested_user_id` FROM `interest_list` WHERE `interest_name` LIKE '%fashion%'
```

But whenever I am trying to export one PHP file by making use of the above MySQL Query then my query is turning to

```
SELECT `interest_id`,`interest_name`,`interested_user_id` FROM `interest_list` WHERE `interest_name` LIKE 'úshion%'
```

SO that it returns no record.
Please tell me how can I solve the issue.
In the export file, I have written the code like:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

//executed code

fputcsv($output, $blankArray);
```

Now please help me.

Actually, I make the query in one file like:

```
$search_sql = "SELECT `interest_id`,`interest_name`,`interested_user_id` FROM `interest_list`";

    if(isset($_REQUEST['search_user_btn'])){

        if($_REQUEST['search_intr'] != '')
$search_sql .= " WHERE `interest_name` LIKE '%".$_REQUEST['search_intr']."%' ";

    }
```

Then in the same file I write like:

```
<a href="export.php?report=interest&qur=<?php echo $search_sql; ?>"><button>Export to CSV</button></a>
```

Finally In the export.php

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
```

I am trying to get the value of $_REQUEST['qur']. But unable to get the original value of $_REQUEST['qur'].

I think Now it is making sense.
Please help....

Comment: How do you determine that the query has changed? Please show the exact code you're using.

Comment: It would be more helpful to show the code where you're generating the SQL, and executing it.

Comment: Please see the above question again, I have modified that.

Comment: Thanks all, I have solved by myself by making use of base64_decode and base64_encode functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't insert random strings in a URL because there're some characters that have a special meaning in URLs. In PHP, you can encode the value of a URL parameter with [rawurlencode()](http://php.net/rawurlencode). Similarly, you can't insert random characters in a HTML string for the same reason.

```
<?php

$url = 'export.php?report=interest&qur=' = rawurlencode($search_sql);

?>
<a href="<?=htmlspecialchars($url)?>"><button>Export to CSV</button></a>
```

Whatever, passing SQL in the URL is call to get hacked.